# Ember View for handlebar helper cannot detect when itself is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have this View for a handlebar helper and I want it to do something when itself is clicked. Nothing is happening though.

```
VpcYeoman.GlassPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['glassWindow'],
  click: function(e) {
    console.log('Embers docs will be their downfall in 2 years because it is unorganized, takes up all of the google search results and gives vague examples if any at all ')
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('float-right-col-minimized');
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('glass-Panel', VpcYeoman.GlassPanelView);
```

`{{#glass-Panel}}  {{/glass-Panel}}` should know when it is clicked using (this) so why isn't this working for me?

Comment: I think is because handlebars helper are compiled to string hence removing all data binding. Just try to use the ember 'render' or 'partial' helper instead of handlebar

Comment: Check the renderTemplate method here http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/
Normally each view is associated with a template so if you render the glass-panel template, the GlassPanelView will automatically be associated, as well as the click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is being handled correctly. The problem is that you're using `$(this)` when you should be using `this.$()`. Here is a working [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nakojira/2/).

Using a helper to render a view does not affect the bindings.

Comment: Would i use `this.$()` if the jquery is inside of an action that is attached to a DOM element?